# Django FileField not cooperating with Python 3's csv module

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have this form:

```
class CSVImportForm(AuthorshipMixin, FormMixin, forms.Form):

    data = forms.FileField()

    def import_csv(self):
        school_csv = csv.DictReader(self.cleaned_data['data'])
        for row in school_csv:
            print(row)
```

The intended purpose of `import_csv()` is to import the CSV to the application's database, but it has been altered for brevity's sake.

An exception occurs when I attempt to iterate over `school_csv`, which I guess is when `DictReader` first attempts to read the file:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  215.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/opt/project/project/import/views.py" in form_valid
  16.         form.import_csv()
File "/opt/project/project/import/forms.py" in import_csv
  67.         for row in school_csv:
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py" in __next__
  109.             self.fieldnames
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py" in fieldnames
  96.                 self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)

Exception Type: Error at /import/
Exception Value: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I don't believe that I was presented with the opportunity to ever choose the mode to open the file with. How am I able to open in text mode so the csv module will handle it?

I've noticed that `InMemoryUploadedFile` has a `file` attribute which seemed useful, but it's a `io.BytesIO` object. I imagine I could do some magic involving manually specifying the encoding.etc but I imagined that this is the sort of thing that Django would make easier.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your post!

Comment: @KlausD.Sorry, done!

Comment: Try to reopen the file in text mode: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.open

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using

```
as_string = self.cleaned_data['data'].read().decode("utf-8")
school_csv = csv.DictReader(as_string)
```

if it expects `str` or

```
from io import StringIO
school_csv = csv.DictReader(StringIO(as_string))
```

if it wants StringIO.

Comment: Easy! Cheers for that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a also a variant with streaming:

```py
reader = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(request.FILE["csv"]))
```

It should work better with huge stuff.